# Where does the resolution stage of Java class loading actually start?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I just finished reading through the Java Virtual Machine Specification and the [section on class loading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html) left me puzzled. As far as I understood it in general and after reading the specification, I thought that the overall *instantiation* of a class consisted of the following steps in the following order:

- **Creation / Loading**: The class loader locates a stream of bytes representing the class, either a file or a network stream or whatever one implements a class loader to fetch. If no class can be found, a `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown. At this point, there is already some basic validation happening where a `ClassFormatError` is thrown if the byte array does not represent a Java class (for example, the magic number is missing) or an `UnsupportedClassVersionError` if the class version is not supported by the running JVM instance.
- **Linking**: The class is hooked into the JVM. If something goes wrong, a subclass of `LinkageError` is thrown. Linking consists of the three substeps:

  - **Verification**: It is made sure that the byte stream represents a Java class as for example that the byte code without formal errors such as overflowing operand stacks for the method byte code. If a class fails verification, a `VerifyError` is thrown.
  - **Preparation**: The JVM allocates memory for all static fields and might create an instance template for speeding up instance creation. Virtual method tables are created. No class loading specific errors are be thrown on this stage. (An `OutOfMemoryError` might be thrown though.)
  - **Resolution**: All symbolic references that were now loaded into the method area in form of the runtime constant pool are resolved to actual types loaded by this JVM. If a symbolic reference can be resolved but results in a conflict of definitions, a `IncompatibleClassChangeError` is thrown. If a referenced class cannot be found, a `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown which basically wraps a `ClassNotFoundException` that was thrown by the class loader attempting to load this referenced class. If a referenced class references itself, a `ClassCircularityError` is thrown. Resolution can happen in one of two flavors which is up to the implementors of the JVM

    1. **Eager**: All symbolic references to other fields, methods or classes are resolved right now.
    2. **Lazy**: Resolving of symbolic references is postponed until the first use of a method. This might bring with it that a class refering to a non-existant class never throws an error if this reference never needs to be resolved.
- **Initialization**: The class's `static` initializers that are defined in the class as Java code are run. If an exception is caused by such an initializer, this exception is rethrown wrapped in an `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

What puzzles me is the *resolution* phase of the above class loading mechanism. Why is resolution defined as an explicit step within *linking* which occurs specifically after *preparation*? Already within the [description of the class *loading* phase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.5), it is mentioned that

> If C has any direct superinterfaces, the symbolic references from C to
>   its direct superinterfaces are resolved using the algorithm of
>   §5.4.3.1.

Are symbolic references not also *resolved* while *verification* occurs since verification is [described](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.1):

> Verification (§4.10) ensures that the binary representation of a class
>   or interface is structurally correct (§4.9). Verification may cause
>   additional classes and interfaces to be loaded (§5.3) but need not
>   cause them to be verified or prepared.

I always have this picture in mind

[image: Java class loading overview]

*Source: http://www.programcreek.com*

which I have seen at almost any place explaining class loading. Should *resolution* not rather be seen as an overall responsibility which is part of all phases, *creation/loading*, *verification*, *linking* and *initialization* (since resolution can be done lazily).

Currently, I would argue that it would make sense to take the resolution stage out of this image and declare it a general procedure that can be used at any time since information about other classes might be required at any stage such that the *loading* of such a class is required what necessarily also requires the *resolution* of the symbolic reference to this class. From the shown picture, it looks like resolution is only happening at a specific point in a chain of separate events.

I suspect that this depiction of *resolution* being a dedicated step maybe just legacy from a time where *resolution* was never conducted lazily but had its place where *all remaining symbolic references* were resolved.

**What I want to know**: Should *resolution* in today's JVMs be understood the way I described it? Or am I wrong about this and *resolution* can still be understood as a dedicated step in a fixed time line just as the image shows it?

Comment: Looks you are right, but definite answer can be obtained only during investigation of JDK sources.

Comment: Very strange concerns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your picture shows resolving as always appearing after preparation but that won’t work. The direct super classes are needed for preparation as you need knowledge about the instance fields of the super classes to determine the object instance memory layout for a particular class. Further, the static initializers of a class and it’s super classes must have been executed before a class can be used, i.e. before creating instances or before invoking static methods.

This differs from the resolution of all other referenced types which can be deferred far longer. It is permissible to resolve a type used in a method just before the method is invoked the first time.

When you look at the beginning of the Chapter [5.4.3. Resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3), there’s stated explicitly:

> The Java Virtual Machine instructions *anewarray*, *checkcast*, *getfield*, *getstatic*, *instanceof*, *invokedynamic*, *invokeinterface*, *invokespecial*, *invokestatic*, *invokevirtual*, *ldc*, *ldc*_w, *multianewarray*, *new*, *putfield*, and *putstatic* make symbolic references to the run-time constant pool. Execution of any of these instructions requires resolution of its symbolic reference.

So the difference is made quite clear. There’s the resolving of the direct super class and the directly implemented interfaces (or super interfaces in case of an interface) which happens early and there’s the resolution of symbolic references for the purpose of the above byte code instructions which can be postponed.

Comment: So there are two views on *resolution*. The *algorithmic resolution* where run time constants are bound to a symbolic value what is described in §5.4.3 and the *resoltion stage* which is nowadays often executed lazily and therefore postponed until the references are actually used?

Comment: [§5.4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3) describes the resolution which can be lazy. The steps described in [§5.3.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.5) are required to be done before using a class.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, but I think you only found a little discrepancy or ambiguity in documentation. The steps in documentation are IMHO not defined very exactly so the implementation may be a little specific, steps may actually overlap a little, etc. The main concern in implementation was probably speed, not the absolute logical clearness.

Try to look into source code of OpenJDK and you might find something interesting.